# Are functions evaluated when passed as parameters?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

if I have some code like this:

```
def handler(self):
   self.run(self.connect)

def connect(self, param):
   #do stuff...

def run(self, connector):
   self.runner = connector
```

What's evaluated first when I call self.run(self.connect)?

run with the stuff in connect already done? or connect with self.connect yet to be evaluated?

Comment: Have you tried putting in a print statements at the beginning of each function?

Comment: Notice that you don't supply an argument for `connect` when you pass it to `run`. If `connect` were called, you'd get an error about the missing argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a function as a parameter does not call it:

```
In [105]: def f1(f):
   .....:     print 'hi'
   .....:     return f
   .....: 

In [106]: def f2():
   .....:     print 'hello'
   .....:     

In [107]: f1(f2)
hi
Out[107]: <function __main__.f2>
```

of course, if you pass a function *call* to another function, what you're passing is the return value:

```
In [108]: f1(f2())
hello
hi
```

Note the order in which they are called:  `f2` is called first, and its return value is passed to `f1`.

Answer (score 2):

None of the code in your question actually calls `connect()`, so the function is never invoked. All that `self.run(self.connect)` does is make `self.runner` a synonym for `self.connect`.